# RTK query mutation updating data but not refreshing page

Tags: typescript, redux, material-ui, rtk-query

I have a mui rating component that rates posts on click. It updates the rating in the data but doesn't refresh the page so it's not disabled after click. I set the disable boolean to check if the rating isn't zero after load and disable accordingly.

Here's the post component with the rating:

```
import { Button, Rating } from "@mui/material";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  useGetPostByIdQuery,
  useUpdatePostByIdMutation,
} from "../../features/api/apiSlice";

type Post = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  userId: number;
  date: string;
  rating: number;
};

export function SinglePost() {
  const { postId } = useParams();
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number | null>();

  const {
    data: post,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    refetch,
  } = useGetPostByIdQuery(Number(postId));

  const [updatePost] = useUpdatePostByIdMutation();

  let title;
  let body;
  let rating;
  if (isSuccess) {
    title = (
      <h1 style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>{post.title}</h1>
    );
    body = <p style={{ color: "white", textAlign: "center" }}>{post.body}</p>;
    rating = (
      <Rating
        key={Math.random()}
        name="size-large"
        size="large"
        value={post.rating}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          updatePost({
            id: Number(postId),
            title: post.title,
            body: post.body,
            userId: post.userId,
            date: post.date,
            rating: Number(newValue),
          });
        }}
        disabled={post.rating !== 0 ? true : false}
      />
    );
  } else if (isError) {
    title = <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>Title Error!</h1>;
    body = <p>Body Error!</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "500px",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(10, 25, 41)",
        width: "500px",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
      }}
    >
      {title}
      <br />
      {body}
      <br />
      {rating}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here's the query mutation in my api slice:

```
import {
  createEntityAdapter,
  createSelector,
  EntityState,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

type Post = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  userId: number;
  date: string;
  rating: number;
};

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000" }),
  tagTypes: ["Posts", "Users"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query<Post[], void>({
      query: () => "/posts",
      transformResponse: (res: Post[]) => res.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id),
      providesTags: (result) =>
        result
          ? [
              ...result.map(({ id }) => ({ type: "Posts" as const, id })),
              { type: "Posts", id: "LIST" },
            ]
          : [{ type: "Posts", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
    getUsers: builder.query<User[], void>({
      query: () => "/users",
      providesTags: ["Users"],
    }),
    getPostById: builder.query<Post, number>({
      query: (id) => `/posts/${id}`,
    }),
    getUserById: builder.query<User, number>({
      query: (id) => `/users/${id}`,
    }),
    updatePostById: builder.mutation<Post, Partial<Post>>({
      query: (post: Post) => {
        const { id, ...body } = post;
        return {
          url: `posts/${id}`,
          method: "PUT",
          body,
        };
      },
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: "Posts", id: "LIST" }],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetPostsQuery,
  useGetUsersQuery,
  useGetPostByIdQuery,
  useGetUserByIdQuery,
  useUpdatePostByIdMutation,
} = apiSlice;
```

Does anyone know why it's not automatically refetching after I change the rating?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your getPostsById was not refecthing data after the updatePost invalidated the `LIST` because the getPostsById provided no tags.

In order to get the subroute for each post to refetch after update you would need to provide the same tag on that endpoint as you are invalidating on the update post endpoint.

So changing the endpoints getPostById and updatePostById to:

```js
{
   getPostById: builder.query<Post, number>({
      query: (id) => `/posts/${id}`,
      provideTags: (_, _, args) => [{ type: "Posts", id: args.id }],
   }),
   updatePostById: builder.mutation<Post, Partial<Post>>({
      query: (post: Post) => {
        const { id, ...body } = post;
        return {
          url: `posts/${id}`,
          method: "PUT",
          body,
        };
      },
      invalidatesTags: (_, _, post) => [{ type: "Posts", id: post.id }],
   }),
}
```